# Using Pnpm with SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, pnpm, sam, pnpm-workspace

I am using PNPM to manage my project and I want to deploy my server app as a Lambda function using SAM. My project structure is organised as follows:

```
- apps
 - server
- packages
 - core
 - utils
```

However, when I run sam build, the node_modules folder is not included, which prevents me from running my program. Is it possible to use PNPM with SAM or do I need to switch to NPM for my deployment process?"

Answer (score 1):

There is a viable solution to this problem. To dereference the symbolic links present in the node_modules folder, we can utilise the `rsync` command. Executing the following command will achieve the desired result:

```
rsync -a --copy-links build-folder destination-folder
```

This command performs a copy of the contents from build-folder to destination-folder, while simultaneously preserving symbolic links as the files they reference.

With this step completed, we can proceed to package all necessary components for deployment to Amazon by running the `sam build` command.